# Rails ignore "nil" values in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still pretty new to rails and this seems pretty basic but I can't find a straight answer.

I have 4 models:

```
def Order
  has_many :payments

def Payment
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :collection
  has_one :dispute

def Collection
  belongs_to :payment

def Dispute
  belongs_to :payment
```

The "show" Order page has the order details and a loop for all payments:

```
<% @order.payments.each do |f| %>
<div class="well">
  <p> Payment Date: <%= f.date_created %> </p>
  <p> Amount: <%= f.amount %> </p>
    ....# some other fields
  <p> Collection Date: <%= f.collection.date_created %> </p>
  <p> Disputed Date: <%= f.dispute.date_created %> </p>
</div>
```

This all works perfect unless there is any value missing in this loop. Which is a lot since many payments don't have "collections" or "disputes". When any value is missing I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Orders#show
undefined method `whatever value is missing' for nil:NilClass
```

Ideally the missing field would simply render blank, but I'm not sure why it breaks the whole view. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`Object#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method, and here is how you'd use it:

```
<% @order.payments.each do |f| %>
<div class="well">
  <p> Payment Date: <%= f.try(:date_created) %> </p>
  <p> Amount: <%= f.try(:amount) %> </p>
    ....# some other fields
  <p> Collection Date: <%= f.try(:collection).try(:date_created) %> </p>
  <p> Disputed Date: <%= f.try(:dispute).try(:date_created) %> </p>
</div>
```

Using `try` like above will make sure that you are not thrown an error, instead it renders blank as you want.

**Update:**

As @muistooshort has commented, `try` should be used cautiously as potential bugs could get swallowed unknowingly.  Use `try` only where it's required; in this case `f.try(:dispute)` and `f.try(:collection)`.

Comment: Putting `try` on them all looks like a good way to hide bugs, if `f.nil?` then `@order.payments` is buggy and should be fixed. Narrowly applying `try` just on the `f.collection.date_created` and `f.dispute.date_created` calls would make more sense, no?

Comment: I believe the `.try` should go on the object you suspect could be nil. So I'd write, e.g., `f.collection.try(:date_created)`. If the object f itself might be nil, and thus we don't want to show anything, I'd use this at the top of the loop: `next if f.nil?`

Comment: @muistooshort, yes selectively applying `try` on attributes would be the way to go.  @user2815613, please have a look at @muistooshort's comment.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I do agree with that something might be buggy, so I'll try to play around with "try" on the other fields and see if I can isolate the issue.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `f.collection.try(:date_created)` and `f.dispute.try(:date_created)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try method -http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

For example, replace

```
<%= f.date_created %>
```

with

```
<%= f.try(:date_created) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NullObject pattern. It's more complex but handling blank value in every possible case can leads you to a lot of spaghetti code. Moreover from my experience `try` method is often overused. Take a look: http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/